# Rails: How to use params from one controller in another controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this form called 'new' like this:

```
<h1> Login</h1>
   <%= form_tag(index_path) do -%>
   <%= label_tag 'Usuário:' -%>
   <%= text_field_tag 'Usuario', '', size: 30-%> <br />
   <%= label_tag 'Senha:' -%>
   <%= password_field_tag 'Senha', '', size: 30-%><br />

<div><%= submit_tag 'Logar' %></div>
<% end -%>`
```

I have a controller called 'login', like this:

```
class LoginController < ApplicationController
   def new  
   end
end
```

I want use this params in another controller called 'github', how i use 'login' params in github controller and views.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow Alex's answer if you want to skip login controller. But if you want to go to github controller via login, then you should use redirect_to. You can pass params in redirect_to like this

```
redirect_to action_name_resource_path(resource_object, param_1: 'value_1', param_2: 'value_2')
```

or
You can also use the object_id instead of the object

```
redirect_to action_name_resource_path(resource_object_id, param_1: 'value_1', param_2: 'value_2')
```

or
if its a collection action like index, you can omit the id as follows

```
redirect_to action_name_resource_path(param_1: 'value_1', param_2: 'value_2')
```

An example with nested resource is as follows:

```
redirect_to edit_user_project_path(@user, @project, param_1: 'value_1', param_2: 'value_2')
```

Comment: But if a use redirect to, the params is seding by URL, visible to user.

Comment: read [this](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/98023#207235) @GuilhermeFreitas. May be this can help you.